# Get link to another taxonomy from a taxonomy list

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently working on a site for an artists directory.

I have two custom taxonomies; `Artists` and `Artist Genre` which will be tied into a `custom post type` of artwork.

I can get a loop to list all of the current `Artist Genre` taxonomies, but I'm tyring to get them to link to go to a page where it will list all of the Artists that are associated with that `Artists Genre` taxonomy.

This is the current loop that I have:

```php
<?php 
$args = array('type' => 'artwork', 'taxonomy' => 'artist-genre', 'hide_empty' => false);
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) {
 $img = get_field('bg-image', 'artist-genre_'. $category->cat_ID .'');
   echo'
   <li>
   <h3><a href=" '. get_term_link($category, $catergory->taxonomy) .' "> '. $category->name . '</a></h3>
    <img src="'. $img['url'] .'" alt="'. $img['alt'] .'" />
     <a class="button" href=" '. get_term_link($category, $catergory->taxonomy) .' ">
       Learn More &rarr;
     </a>
   <li>';
 }
?>
```

I know I have the `get_term_link()` to get the term of the taxonomy of the Artists Genre, but I'm not sure how to get it so it links to a page to list all of the artists that are associated with that genre. I'm also not sure if I need to re-structure my `custom post types` and custom `taxonomy` structure to make it work correctly either.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I did something similar a couple of years ago with wordpress and used [advancedcustomfields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which I found very useful when dealing with `custom post types`, `taxonomies` and relations. ACF documentation is very clear and [get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/) may be handy. Good luck

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I'm not sure if ACF might be the right way to go. I'm using CPT UI to create the custom taxonomies and I just don't know if it's possible to get both of them with the attached post type.